# Member class instantiation

Tags: c++, templates

`N4296::14.7.1/1 [temp.inst]` told us the following:

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes
>   the implicit instantiation of the **declarations**, but not of the
>   **definitions**, [...], **member classes**, [...]

What is that rule about? Let me give you an example:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
public:
    template<class W> class Y; //1, declaration
    template<class V> class U{ V v; };  //2, definition
};

A<int> a; //3, implicit instantiation
int main(){ }
```

Does implicit instantiation at `//3` cause implicit instantiation at `//2` and at `//1`? If so, what template argument was used to instantiate those member classes?

Comment: They are not member classes. They are member templates.

Comment: I don't believe this is an instantiation of a class template specialization, unless my standardese is confused. Also, the member classes are not instantiated, regardless.

Comment: @T.C. You're right, but it's unclear how we can instantiate a member class. I thought, the class is being instantiated when we define a varible of that class. For instance, in [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb95a957e599d35d) example what class is going to be instantiated?

Comment: In that case, it instantiates the declarations for `A<int>::Y` and `A<int>::U` (just like a forward declaration), but not the definitions.

Comment: @T.C. What does "instantiate a declaration" mean? Does the Standard explcicitly define that concept? I couldn't find it, serching the "instantiates the declarations".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special about those member templates, compared to the "outer" template. The compiler reads them as a declaration, such that it knows that there exist names as `A<T>::Y<W>` and `A<T>::U<V>`, much the same as when you declare the template for class A:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
     int a;
};
```

Which also only declares the existence of a class `A<T>` but does not instantiate it.

Instantiation is deferred until a templated type is actually used (or explicitly instantiated), which equally applies to the member templates.

Comment: Did you mean that a template doesn't contain any member until it has been instantiated? When we're instantiating the template we're also instatiating declarations of the member classes of the class being instatiated.

Comment: Templates are 'pseudo-code'. After the compiler has parsed the template text, no code nor data exists (yet) but the compiler will take the declared names into account in name-resolution. If, at some point, the name-resolving leads to the decision to actually _use_ (one of) the templated names, then the compiler starts to generate (=instantiate) the actual code + data for the templated type or function and its dependents.